What does this error mean when I am manually installing Ubuntu onto my second hard drive and how can I fix it?
I am presently trying to install the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS desktop version onto my second separate hard drive using a Ventoy USB and I boot using UEFI. My settings before initiating the installation is as follows:

Install without internet connection;
Install with minimal software (ie. browser and other basics); and
Install without proprietary third party software.

The procedure for how I setup the manual partition is as follows:

Set first partition as Swap 1GB;
Set second partition as root (/) and used as ext4; and
Set third partition as home (/home) and used as ext4.

After all of this setup I begin the installation and receive the following error part way through the installation process (If need be I can provide an entire error log).
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-kernel: FAIL: installing kernel
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             ret = args.func(args)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2234, in curthooks
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             builtin_curthooks(cfg, target, state)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2058, in builtin_curthooks
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             install_kernel(cfg, target)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 403, in install_kernel
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             install(kernel_cfg.package)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 369, in install
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             distro.install_packages([pkg], target=target, env=env)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 474, in install_packages
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             return install_cmd('install', args=pkglist, opts=opts, target=target,
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 256, in run_apt_command
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             cmd_rv = apt_install(mode, args, opts=opts, env=env, target=target,
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 307, in apt_install
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             cmd_rv = inchroot.subp(cmd + inst_opts + packages, env=env)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 843, in subp
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             return subp(*args, **kwargs)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 323, in subp
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:             return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 172, in _subp
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Exit code: 100
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Stdout: ''
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Stderr: ''
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Unexpected error while running command.
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Exit code: 100
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Reason: -
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Stdout: ''
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]:         Stderr: ''
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]: 
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_log.2514[12184]: Stderr: ''
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_event.2514[2514]:  executing curtin install curthooks step
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_event.2514[2514]: 
Oct 31 09:54:39 ubuntu subiquity_event.2514[2514]:   curtin command install

I want to start learning Linux but I can't start learning till I manage to install it, so I am hoping some folks could help me out. Thanks.

Understood. In retrospect that is valuable information that totally slipped my mind, my apologies. I am certain it is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS for Desktop. The original post will be edited to reflect this. Thanks.

An old bug but this might still be relevant. See the following link https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1952603

Has BIOS or UEFI boot

Good point. My PC uses UEFI to boot. Original post will be edited to reflect this information.

I've installed Ubuntu 20 times or more. It's very straightforward. After creating the installation media (USB) Make sure you set BIOS to boot from USB - (Hold down F12 on boot), and boot up. Choose 'erase disk and install 20.04' when prompted by the installer and click next.  The installer creates the appropriate partitions. Ubuntu no longer uses a swap partition, so that isn't necessary. A 532mb FAT32 grub partition may be created--(You can resize/create partitions after the install). And wifi and wifi drivers are a must. A wired connection is almost a requirement with Ubuntu these days. I've had to use a cable every time for the last few years.  - Hope this helps.

Start a live Ubuntu session.
Once the boot is complete, check that everything is working properly, especially the network connection and that there is Internet communication.
Start the Ubuntu installation, when you get to the partitioning, choose manual instead of automatic.
Select the hard drive.
Check that Grub is installed on it.
Create a new partition table, a raw partition will be created automatically.
Create an ext4 partition for /, 60 gigabytes if you have it available.
Create a swap system partition, double the amount of RAM for common use, triple if you hibernate.
Create an ext4 partition for /home, whatever else you want.
Apply the changes and continue the installation.
If you want to learn GnuLinux, Debian with FluxBox or XFCE would be ideal.
